# iOS Tabbar UITabbarItem decrease size after tap

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios8, uitabbaritem, xcode6gm

I'm using storyboard and a TabbarViewController. The tabbaritems decrease their size after tapping. The images are set in a NavigationController, the name in the NavigationController is the name of the imageset in Images.xcassets. The sizes of the images in Images.xcassets are 25x25 (1x), 50x50 (2x) and 75x75 (3x).
Do I have to do sth. programmatically?

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16717624/pic.png)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug which appear when you set image insets. It seems as if image insets are applied every time you tap. The only way to avoid it seems to be either not to use image insets or set them this way: left+right =0 and top+bottom=0

I've filed a bug in bugreport.apple.com, as well as openradar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4938457482788864